# How to setup your NTFS drives/partitions to mount on elementary OS startup?

Tags: startup, ntfs

I have installed elementary OS freya installed on a drive which also contains another ntfs partition which I would like to mount at system startup.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 7):

Easy to set up using fstab. Run `sudo blkid`

and you should get something like this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="b9377d9b-639f-47da-ae99-efe277eb56b3" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Backup 1" UUID="6177d371-80e4-49bd-bb77-de269e175c97" TYPE="ext4"
```

Save the UUID of the partition you want to mount. If you are unsure of the partition you want to mount use `sudo fdisk -l` to get more details of the partition.

Now edit your `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /etc/fstab
```

Add the following lines to your file:

```
#Windows Partition
UUID=<xxxxx> <mount point> ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

You must replace the `<xxxx>` with your UUID and `<mount point>` with your desired mount point.

For the mount point you can choose something like `/media/<user>/windows` (which is the standard mount point for other partitions) or create a folder (without spaces) in your home directory and use `/home/<user>/<folder>` as the mount point.

Your file should look like this in the end:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b9377d9b-639f-47da-ae99-efe277eb56b3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=89bfd6b9-b2be-41c1-8c9f-5e7e5cb738d3 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#Windows Partition
UUID=b9377d9b-639f-47da-ae99-efe277eb56b3 /media/tim/windows ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

After editing the file you should run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

If it returns any error, **Do not Reboot** (your PC may fail to restart), as you probably have some error in the mount point.

If everything goes well you should see your partition mounted.

[Source, Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)

Comment: Is there a bug report on Ubuntu / elementary to make this more user friendliy? It's been like this for years and I think it is unacceptable hassle for most endusers. Why is permanently mounting not as as easy as temporarily mounting...

Comment: I do understand the concept of /etc/fstab but when I enter my partitions I want to share with a parallel windows boot (ntfs and exfat patitions) my eOS Juno does not boot properly (not before i comment them all out). As they are commented out I cannot do an mount -a either. So I end up clicking on all partitions in the files app to get a dynamic mount before starting things like my firefox (have a profile on one of the shared partitions). Is that the way it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 5):

If you like GUIs and / or are afraid to access directly the config files, a good option is Gnome Disks.

Install via `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

You can set to mount at startup like this:

[image: Edit mount options]

[image: Set options]

Comment: Thank you bro! This what a need to people with GUI =) Its to hard make it by command line when u have GUI )

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what we needed. "it's easy, just edit fstab and type like 4892 commands and learn how to use a config file" no man, we're in 2019 now. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Mounting a Windows partition that is encrypted with BitLocker is probably not supported?

Answer (score -3):

i use PySDM, it easy way to auto mount my partitions, step to do:

1. Go to http://pysdm.sourceforge.net download and open it with root permission;
2. Look to left side "Partition List" to see your device or your partition (fat/fat32/ntfs...), enter that partition;
3. At right side, give it a name. (you can see mount point for further access)
4. Mount it.
5. Good Lucks

Comment: This looks like a good tool. Could you elaborate your answer with steps to install it and auto mount an ntfs partition?

Comment: Please expand your answer and provide necessary details. If not an answer then use comments.