# How to read and write HD formatted with NTFS elementary OS?

Tags: ntfs

I hard drives formatted with NTFS Windows 10. I want to read and write to these drives with elementary OS. How can I do?

NB: this solution don't work:
[How to setup your NTFS drives/partitions to mount on elementary OS startup?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/215/how-to-setup-your-ntfs-drives-partitions-to-mount-on-elementary-os-startup)

Comment: Is Files listing these hard drives on the sidebar? What are the errors you're getting when trying to open these drives?

Answer (score 3):

if you need it to mount automatically, you can use fstab:

```
~#vim etc/fstab
```

*(or any another text editor you'd prefer.)*

generally, fstab holds information about HDDs on your system which will (try to) be mounted on startup.

**BACK IT UP!**

your NTFS petition probably isn't there, you want to find its UUID with

```
~# blkid
```

which will print something like

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="80D42D64D42D5DA2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="7A58439F584358D1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="storeage" UUID="82AE2422AE2410E9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="40eafe67-64b6-4916-a310-0688a6c17675" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="e9c1e289-075d-449d-90db-a84a11baaeed" TYPE="swap"
```

i want storeage (ik about the misspell D:) to be mounted on boot, so i add a new line to fstab:

```
UUID=82AE2422AE2410E9
```

now you want to specify the **mount point** for the petition:

```
/media/storeage
```

now we tell the system to use `ntfs-3g` which is a recent lib that handles read/write to ntfs petitions, and a whole lot of another stuff related to it:

```
ntfs-3g auto,users,exec,permissions 0 0
```

please note the `exec` after `users`, it tells the system it is permitted to execute anything on the ntfs petition (executable bit always on) and this is a huge security hole, i just need it for my own reasons ;)

so the whole thing goes like

```
UUID=82AE2422AE2410E9 /media/storeage ntfs-3g auto,users,exec,permissions 0 0
```

or

```
UUID=<your_uuid> <mount point> ntfs-3g auto,users,exec,permissions 0 0
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the device path:

```
parted -l
```

It will show some like this:

```
Modelo: ATA HGST HTS545050A7 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 500GB

Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/4096B

Tabla de particiones. gpt


Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Sistema de archivos  
Nombre                        Banderas

 1      1049kB  316MB  315MB   ntfs                 Basic data 
partition          oculta, diag

 2      316MB   420MB  105MB   fat32                EFI system 
partition          arranque

 3      420MB   555MB  134MB                        Microsoft reserved 
partition  msftres

 4      555MB   108GB  107GB   ntfs                 Basic data 
partition          msftdata

 9      108GB   407GB  299GB   
ntfs                                               msftdata

 8      407GB   444GB  37.6GB  ext4

 7      444GB   470GB  25.4GB  ext4

11      470GB   493GB  23.6GB  freebsd-ufs          bsd

10      493GB   495GB  2147MB                       1

 6      495GB   500GB  4295MB  linux-swap(v1)

 5      500GB   500GB  472MB   
ntfs                                               oculta, diag
```

Look for the partition you want to mount, 9 in this case.

Try mounting:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o defaults,rw,uid=1000,users /dev/sda9 /media /mount-point
```

If it works, replace `UUID` in `/etc/fstab` (at partition config) with device path like `/dev/sdXY`.

PostData: Mount point must have been created

```
sudo mkdir /media/some-dir-name
```