# External HDD doesn't appear in Files

Tags: pantheon-files, mount

I am trying to connect an NTFS-formatted hard drive with a USB-SATA adapter, but for some reason it won't appear in the devices list in Files unless I mount it manually.

[image: HDD not listed when initially plugged in]

However if I mount it manually with `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/mike`, it appears:

[image: HDD listed when mounted manually]

Why does it not appear when first plugged in?

Relevant output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 625141759 625139712 298.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: A bug concerning this should be raised at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files.  I have had a look at the code and identified a possible cause.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. I find it very anoying that my usb-sticks (automounted or just listed) don't appear in the list. VERY anoying to not be able to simply access them. Quite frankly, it behaves as if they aren't even plugged in, even if I was able to just access them without trouble in a plasma-session.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. I find it very anoying that my usb-sticks (automounted or just listed) don't appear in the list. VERY anoying to not be able to simply access them. Quite frankly, it behaves as if they aren't even plugged in, even if I was able to just access them without trouble in a plasma-session.

Comment: I'll report it now - I also have a couple of regular USB drives I can test with. What do you think the cause could be?

Comment: @JeremyWootten Bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1659611.

Comment: I have reported this bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1659611). If you can you should mark that it affects you to.

Comment: There is a potential fix linked with the bug report but it needs testing by someone who experiences this problem and is capable of building the branch from source code (needs bzr, cmake and valac as well as usual build tools and build-deps)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other file managers, Pantheon Files doesn't auto-mount external drives. There is an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1094669) for adding this feature.

If you'd like USB drives to auto-mount, you can install a file manager that offers this feature, such as Nautilus. If you'd like to auto-mount just this one drive, you can make that change [using Gnome Disk Utility](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2640/792) or by [editing `/etc/fstab/`](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/607/792).

Comment: I should edit my question to be clearer perhaps. I understand that Pantheon Files doesn't support auto-mount, however this does not explain why the drive doesn't even show up in the 'Devices' list. For example, the internal 500GB drive shows up despite the fact it isn't actually mounted, so why doesn't the external drive?