# auto mount sd card on elementary os

Tags: release-loki, filesystem

I'm trying to mount a sd card on elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit). The drive is recognized in `gparted` and with `sudo fdisk -l` but I fail mounting it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just mastered to auto mount the card. Had to install `exfat-fuse exfat-utils` can we put these packages into the core?

Comment: Does it appear in the devices list in Files? If not, it could be similar to the issue I experienced [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/external-hdd-doesnt-appear-in-files). Does it give an error message when you try mounting it? Could you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your post?

Comment: Yes it appears in pantheon-files and also with the `sudo fdisk-l` and gparted but the file system is `exfat`. And when I tried to mount it with `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /media` following message appear `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
`

Comment: And the output of the `fdisk`: `Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.5 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
`

Comment: But after I installed `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` and restarted the system the card is mounted and accessible through pantheon-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install

```
sudo apt install exfat-fuse 
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

I am just making an answer so that it is solved and people know this.  I always have this problem with every distribution.. except I think Mate may have included it.

Answer (score 0):

> I usually don't go for the GUI option. But in this case, it was the quickiest.

1. Open Application menu and type or find Disks app.
2. Find the SD card and click on the play button to mount its partition.